# Windows Forms Application and Console in C++ Visual Studio 10

Tags: c++

For some reason if you were to create a windows form application in visual studio 10 using C++ and put a console writeline statement and run it. The console doesn't come up but the form still shows. I am trying to create an application that uses both windows forms and a console but am unsuccessful. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? It should be a very simple solution. Is it even possible to have a console and a windows form in a c++ application? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's a pointer: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/314783/Merging-Console-application-with-Windows-Form-Appl, also that question has been asked before.

Comment: Just change the linker option: Project + Properties, Linker, System, SubSystem = Console.

Comment: It was too easy. All I did was add the this line of code to my headers section #include "windows.h" and right before I have the Console::Writeline("Hello world") statement I put  AllocConsole(); . Et viola! Apparently what this does is allocates memory for a console window to appear. Theoretically you shouldn't have to call this method but in some cases with some compilers I guess you have to. Thanks everyone for their help!